# ListView onItemClickListener isn't called

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I was trying to make a custom `ListView`. The ListView contains a `RelativeLayout` who contains a `TextView` and a `Switch`. When you press on the Switch the Switch have to change from true to false (and vice versa).

This is my getView method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_gproblem, null);

    //vi.setClickable(true); Tried this
    //vi.setFocusable(true);

    TextView txt_comment_description = (TextView) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.txt_comment_description);
    txt_comment_description.setText(MyTasks.allGComments.get(position)
            .getProblemDescription());
    //txt_comment_description.setFocusable(false); Tried this
    //txt_comment_description.setClickable(false);

    Switch switch_comment = (Switch) vi.findViewById(R.id.switch_comment);
    //switch_comment.setFocusable(false); Tried this
    //switch_comment.setClickable(false);

    //First time running getMyGComments returns a empty ArrayList
    if (MyTasks.allCustomers.get(ServerData.myID - 1).getMyGComments()
            .size() > position) {
        switch_comment.setChecked(MyTasks.allCustomers
                .get(ServerData.myID - 1).getMyGComments().get(position)
                .isProblemValue());
    }
    return vi;
}
```

This is my onClickListener:

```
list_quality.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

               //Do Something
            }
        });
```

My `onItemClickListener` isn't called when I click on the TextView, Switch or on the space between the two objects. When I hit the switch the switch acts normally (the state changes). But my `onItemClickListener` isn't called. I tried to disabled `clickable` and `focusable` of the Switch and the TextView but that doesn't work either.

The setOnItemClickListeren is executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the line below to the listview row's container:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Remove all clickables/focusables from wherever you put them. Then the onItemClick should be called if you press on the whole item.

Also, if you would like to have buttons inside the listview row clickable as well, add an onClickListener to the button inside your ListView adapter getView() method.

Answer (score 3):

Some UI elements may get the focus instead of the list item so use this to get it back

```
android:focusable="false"
```